# Venn Diagrams are contradicting the definition

Tags: logic

We had the following homework:

∪i∈I (Fi∩Gi) = ∪i∈I Fi ∩ ∪i∈I Gi

Which is easily proven by statements and logic, take an X out of the first set and use equivalent arrows to reach the other set.

I wanted for the sake of helping my understanding of how these sets look like to draw venn diagrams. However I got stuck when I found it that my first example broke this equality!

My constructed example: I is defined to be {1,2,3}

So I draw up 3 F sets and 3 G sets

[My example Venn-diagramm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJi5w.png)

∪i∈I (Fi∩Gi) That should be equal to  (F(1) ∩ G(1)) ∪ (F(2) ∩ G(2)) 
∪ (F(3) ∩ G(3))

So the following area

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2oPt.png)

*Green arrow says : it stays empty

However

∪i∈I Fi ∩ ∪i∈I Gi is equal to (F(1)∪F(2)∪F(3))  ∩  (G(1)∪G(2)∪G(3) ) right?
So this area *red with black stripes

[∪i∈I Fi ∩ ∪i∈I Gi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dEVq.png)

Which is clearly NOT the same area since F(2)∩ G(2) = the empty set!

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right-hand side of your wrong equation, the scope of the first $i$ and the scope of the second $i$ are separate. Therefore you could change the second $i$ to a $j$, and the meaning of the right-hand side would not change. I mean that  you could write $\cup_{i \in I} F_i \cap \cup_{j \in I} G_j$. Try doing this, and try to see where your "double arrows" argument breaks down.

Comment: Hello what do you mean with "the scope of the first I and the second I?" I have a hard time understanding this part of your reply. English is sadly not my mother tounge. Even though I understand your words, I am not sure I am imagining the concept of your argumentation. 

Nevertheless thanks for your fast reply. I will try to see what is this new equation you gave me.

Comment: Nvm I am stupid. the equation at the top is obviously false ∪i∈I (Fi∩Gi) = ∪i∈I Fi ∩ ∪i∈I Gi does not apply in both directions thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Spent two hours on a wrong equation :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems your argument is right. Indeed the said equation is false unless you have additional hypothesis.

Here is another explicit counterexample: consider the sets
$$F_1=\{1\} \ F_2=\{2\}$$
and the sets
$$G_1=\{2\}\ G_2=\{1\}$$

Clearly we have that for every index $i$ the following holds
$$F_i \cap G_i = \emptyset$$ 
so 
$$\bigcup_i (F_i \cap G_i) = \emptyset\ .$$

On the other hand 
$$\bigcup_i F_i = \bigcup_i G_i =\{1,2\}$$
so 
$$(\bigcup_i F_i) \cap (\bigcup_i G_i)=\{1,2\}\ .$$

Elaborating a little bit on Simon's answer: the problem lies in the fact that in  $\bigcup_i (F_i \cap G_i)$ you put only those elements for which there's an index $i$ such that the said element belongs to both $F_i$ and $G_i$, in $\bigcup_i F_i \cap \bigcup_i G_i$ instead you take also those elements the belongs to an $F_i$ and $G_j$ where the indexes $i$ and $j$ may not be equal.

Comment: Thank you for reply and elaboration. Really helps. I will give this topic a deeper look today and reply here incase i have more questions about it. I upvoted both of you.

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for the upvote. Lol someone must have downvoted my reply, since it's on zero total votes :)

Comment: Hey can you please confirm this? 

∪i,j∈ I  ( Fi∩Gj)
is the same as (F(1)∩G(1)) ∪ (F(1)∩G(2)) ∪(F(1)∩G(3)) ∪(F(2)∩G(1)) ∪ (F(2)∩G(2)) ∪ (F(2)∩G(3)) ∪ (F(3)∩G(1)) ∪ (F(3)∩G(2)) ∪ (F(3)∩G(3))

Comment: @MadSpaceMemer yes it is.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if two indexes are separate and not related to eachother, even tho they are same, you can change just rename them? right?

Comment: @MadSpaceMemer do you mean like in $(\bigcup_i F_i) \cap (\bigcup_i G_i)$?

Comment: I suppose that could be an example. yes